# Is there a possibility to assign sales organization at product level in SAP Hybris Commerce?

Tags: product, sap-commerce-cloud, catalog

We are using sap hybris 2005 and we need to associate a product to specific sales organization. In Hybris we can work through Base Store object but just at catalog level, so we have relation one or more catalogs to one Base Store.

Anybody knows if there's a way to have a relation at single Product level?

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple solution for this but every solution has different benefit. You need to ask what is your expectation. Some of them:

- Using different catalog
- Using product attributes
- Using classifications
- Using custom code